# Zend framework Interface 'Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface' not found

Tags: php, zend-framework3

Hi i've followed the getting started tutorial on Zend framework 3, and managed to get it working. So then i decided to download a new skeleton application and adapt it as like a online shop. But when i go to run the module.php file through wamp i get this error message:

> Fatal error: Interface 'Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface' not
>   found in C:\wamp64\www\shop\module\Shop\src\Module.php on line 13

I have also tried including Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface in modules.config.php but it didnt work. Ha anyone else had the same issue? i'm pulling my hair out to try and get it to work.

Thatnks to anyone willing to help :)

Comment: Do you have `zendframework/zend-modulemanager` installed?

Comment: i did have zendframework/zend-modulemanager installed, The problem was, that i was trying to open the module.php file, while instead i should have been entering the route i had defined in module.config.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that i was trying to open the module.php file, while instead i should have been entering the route i had defined in module.config.php